# Doubt regarding uniform continuity.

Tags: integration, proof-verification, continuity

In [this page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_is_Riemann_Integrable), the proof mentions that the following results from the definition of uniform continuity, and that the below inequality is implied by $|x-y|<\delta$:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$$

But in [the page defining uniform continuity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Uniform_Continuity/Real_Numbers), it says that $|x-y|<\delta \implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

From where does the $\frac{1}{b-a}$ term come from in the first webpage's proof, and why does it hold true?

Comment: Since $a,b$ are constant, and presumably $a < b$, the quantity
$$\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$$
is just another potential "$\epsilon$", so author's choice (whatever is more convenient).

Comment: Noted. Thanks :) @quasi

Answer (score 2):

The key is that for *any* $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

In particular, if we are given a particular positive real number $\varepsilon$, then we can apply the above to $\eta=\frac{\varepsilon}{b-a}>0$ to obtain a $\delta$ for which $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\eta$.

Comment: Silly question from my side. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a choice to make the proof come out cleaner. Don't worry, when I encountered stuff like this for the first time, I was confused.

The epsilon in the definition need not actually be an epsilon in the proof. The idea is that we bound $|f(x) - f(y)|$ from above by something small. This epsilon can be as small as we wish - as one of my analysis professors said, "It's the same among friends."